# How can you insert a "times/divide" symbol similar to the "plus/minus" (±) one?

Tags: symbols

Is there a LaTeX symbol for it?

A non-educated guess is that it may look like the figure below.

[image: geometric mean and geometric standard deviation operator]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Comment: I tried the Detexify earlier, but it was unable to find the symbol I was looking :(

Comment: That's something to mention when you first post.  Generally, you want to let us know  what you've tried, so that we don't spend our time re-trying the same things.

Comment: Never heard of times devide before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\timesdiv{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{%
   $\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\times\\[-1.667ex]\div\end{array}$}}}}

\begin{document}
$d\timesdiv b$ 

$d\pm b$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably the `\timesdiv` works. I will check if it is the correct symbol for representing what I want